# "Subscript requires Array or Pointer" Error

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am trying to find the sum of values in an array, but keep getting different type of errors.  I am currently getting a "subscript requires array or pointer" type error.

My code for user entering input values:

```
int userNums() {
    int valueArray[SIZE] = { 0 }; // array to hold input values 
    int count;  // for loop counter 
    for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) {
        printf("Enter value %i of %i:\n", count +1, SIZE);
        scanf_s("%i", valueArray[]);
    }

    return valueArray[SIZE];
}
```

My code for finding the sum:

```
int getSum(int valueArray[SIZE]) {
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) {
        sum += valueArray[count];
    }
    printf("The sum of all numbers entered is: %i\n", sum);
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s("%i", valueArray[]);` --> `scanf_s("%i", &valueArray[count]);`

Comment: Here `return valueArray[SIZE];` you want to return one-one element or complete array ? If you want to return whole array, then its not correct as `valueArray` is locally created array, _scope ends in this function itself, returning local array will cause *undefined behavior*_

Comment: You need to read the chapter dealing with arrays and pointers in your C text book.

Comment: ...and malloc, to alocate an array dynamically which you _can_ return.

Comment: ... additionnally you cannot return a whole array from a function in C.